# Redis persistent installation with more data than RAM

Tags: memory, redis

I'm new to Redis, but lately they've started to promote the idea of using Redis as a general purpose persistent db, instead of mainly for cache. I think this would be a good fit for an app I want to write.

The issue is: I need more memory (let's say 3Gb) than what I'll have available in RAM (say, 2Gb). Redis runs entirely in RAM if I'm not mistaken ("[data sets can't be larger than memory](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/faq/)"). However, most of the data will only need to be seldomly accessed. I need all data to persist, but I'd need >1Gb present all time, the rest could be evicted.

**Question**: Only using Redis, is it possible to have a larger data set persist as disk storage, but only load a subset of keys to RAM and evict less-frequently-used keys as needed to make space for new less-frequenly-used keys? *I don't want to evict keys and then have them deleted or not stored in disk storage*.

Apparently, there used to be a swap or virtual memory option, but it's now deprecated.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible... disk storage seems to be just for images of the whole db. It's a pity, but one can always pair it up with another disk based db

Comment: we can not usually help with your [capacity planning](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning) but if you already aware of this, that you want redis, then you might also want to use a server with enough capacity for handling this. I would think since this is a more relevant question for stackoverflow.com, because in the end IMHO you seems to try to fix a [x and y problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem) redis might work for you but consider other options. maybe a standard database with a sql Db might a option

Comment: @djdomi Thanks! I was in doubt as to whether I should post it there, but thought it could make more sense to post it here. On second thought, I think Redis employees monitor SO, not sure if it they also monitor other SE stacks. But in regard to my question, it may be possible after all: https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/technology/redis-on-flash/